# How do wikipedia make the pop ups on certain links?

Tags: hyperlink, hover, wikipedia

Wondering how Wikipedia make the small popups on their links. Is it a js library or something else? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page

Hover over any of the links in the main body of content and you will see additional info pop up.

I was thinking it was some kind of place holder but can't see any reference in their code.

Answer (score 1):

A JS library plus a Node.js service for the content of the popup. The code is in the [Popups](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Popups) extension.